# After indexing there is a new "undefined" collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing

after i created a index in a mongodb. there wil be a new "undefined" collection in that database.

the document of the undefinded collection looks like that:

```
   {"_id":"5caf6025a8741f81eb58ebf9",
     "ns":"bigChart.14-csv_4/11/2019:2:52:28 PM",
     "key":{"frame":1},
     "name":"frame_1",
     "unique":false
   }
```

i use this code to create a index:

```
   function createIndexFrame(dbObject,collectionName, callback)
   {
      dbObject.collection(collectionName).createIndex({frame:1},function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback();
    });
   }
```

why do i get a new "undefined" collection?

cheers pau

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: When you log out `collectionName`, what do you get? I'm guessing `undefined`

Comment: @djheru
mongodb will create the index on the right collection. but also a new undefined collection is created. so the collectionName can not be empty.

Comment: @iofjuupasli
https://github.com/chrisEAH/sensorikFillDB/blob/master/app/fillServer.js